# C buffer overflow getting Segmentation Fault

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault, buffer-overflow

I am trying to do a buffer-overflow for my security class, we are not allowed to call any function and we need to jump to secret function and also return 0 without segmentation fault. I wrote the code below and successfully jumped to secret but I am getting a segmentation fault. How can I terminate the program successfully? Or is it possible to just write to a single address instead of for loop, when I tried it did not change anything.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void secret()
{
    printf("now inside secret()!\n");
}

void entrance()
{
    int doNotTouch[10];
    // can only modify this section BEGIN
    // cant call secret(), maybe use secret (pointer to function)
    for (int i = 0; i < 14; i++) {
        *(doNotTouch + i) = (int) &secret;
    }
    // can only modify this section END
    printf("now inside entrance()!\n");
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    entrance();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In some semi-assembler, assuming some kind of x86.  (BP is pseudocode for EBP or RBP, assuming you're not actually compiling for 16-bit mode.  32-bit mode is likely so `int` is the same width as a return address.)

```
; entrance:
; - stack has return address to main
push  bp                         ; decrement SP by a pointer width
mov   bp,sp
sub   sp, 10*sizeof(int)         ; reserve space for an array
;....
; doNotTouch[0] is probably at [bp - 10*sizeof(int)]
```

When you loop to 14, you first overwrite the saved bp at i==10 and then the return address to main (which is correct) and then overwrite some more which eventually causes the seg fault. So you only need to do `*(doNotTouch + 11) = (int) &secret;` - assuming int is the size of a function pointer.  (Or a bit more if the compiler left a gap for stack-alignment or its own use.  In a debug build other locals will have stack slots.  Overwriting them could lead to an infinite loop that goes out of bounds.)

Then follows your printf and then the function returns, but it does not return to main but "jumps" to `secret`.

When `secret` returns, it is actually now the return from main but it couldn't do the `return 0;`

So secret should be:

```
int secret()
{
    printf("now inside secret()!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Disclaimer: "....I think."

Comment: I tried *(doNotTouch + 11) = (int) &secret; but nothing happens, program executes normally and I am not allowed to add return 0 to secret. Why do you think right number is 11? doNotTouch consists of ints so I thought it would be 4 bytes * 10 = 40 bytes and the frame ptr (4 bytes I guess) so (doNotTouch + 44) was my guess, doesnt it matter if it is an integer or char?

Comment: `int doNotTouch[10];` is 0..9; index 10 is bp; index 11 is return address. But you _could_ inspect the assembler and you _could_ run it in the debugger to see what happens. In your original code there is also an int i. And some compilers allocate more than 10.